# Random 403 error during resolving packages on Artifactory

Tags: apache, maven, jenkins, artifactory

We use Artifactory Pro. 
We have a virtual repo in which we've stored the installer of [yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/) 23.04. 
On another instance we have running a Jenkins 1 server. We have some maven project and our maven goal is to perform:

```
clean source:jar install -DskipTests -Pyarn -X
```

We use the profile yarn so a `yarn install` will be executed.
We are not using any proxy about our configuration. We have turned them off explicitly
Most of the time the jenkins job works:

```
[INFO] yarn install v0.23.4
[INFO] [1/4] Resolving packages...
[INFO] [2/4] Fetching packages...
[ERROR] warning fsevents@1.1.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
[INFO] info "fsevents@1.1.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[INFO] [3/4] Linking dependencies...
[ERROR] warning "ng2-translate@5.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@^2.0.0".
[ERROR] warning "ng2-translate@5.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/http@^2.0.0".
[ERROR] warning "sass-loader@6.0.5" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0".
[INFO] [4/4] Building fresh packages...
[INFO] success Saved lockfile.
```

But on certain occasions it fails:

```
[INFO] yarn install v0.23.4
[INFO] [1/4] Resolving packages...
[ERROR] an unexpected error occurred: "http://xxx/artifactory/api/npm/npm/xxx: Request\ "http://xxx/artifactory/api/npm/npm/xxx" returned a 403
```

The yarn is in our artifactory. So we think the only issue can be a 'bad connection' between jenkins and Artifactory or the apache which is running above Artifactory.

Is there some specific setting in Apache that could cause this behaviour of Artifactory?

Comment: You seemed to be having issues with your NPM registry ..have you correctly configured the usage of the registry? Apart from that 403 error code means having wrong authentication data...so you have a problem in your configuration  for accessing the repository manager...

Comment: @khmarbaise but it works most of the time. The module in the npm registry is always different so it happens on random moments, on random modules. I know a 403 is a forbidden error (authentication) but in this case it acts more like a sort of timeout error. Maybe the connection breaks during authenticating (resolving) a package?

Comment: If it only works most of the time...than the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: @khmarbaise that's the reason I was thinking about a timeout in apache/artifactory/connection somewhere. But I don't know how to debug. I've now requested the logs of the apache of our Artifactory. I hope I can make this question more clear with that

Comment: A 403 error is for authorization, not authentication. 401 means that I don't believe you are who you are. 403 means I believe who you are, but you don't have access to what you are trying to get to. I know that doesn't help with your problem, exactly. It could be something like a connection problem to LDAP to get the groups associated with a user. Seems like a bit of a stretch, but maybe that will help your research go off in the right direction.

Comment: We're having the same problem. Which version of Artifactory pro are you using?

Comment: @rwilson04 5.4.5